# Select and display columns with hasMany relation Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have troubles with selecting from two tables with `hasMany`, `belongsToMany` etc relations.

I have table `items`

```
id 
title
```

and table `review`

```
id
item_id
```

this is in my Item model

```
public function review()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review', 'item_id','id');
}
```

In my Review model

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_id','id');
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $reviews = Review::with('item')->get();
    return view('index', compact('reviews'));
}
```

and in view I want to show all `reviews` from Reviews table and `titles` from items table.

```
@foreach($reviews as $review)    
     {!!$review->item()->title!!}    
@endforeach
```

The error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ps.item_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `items`.*, `item_id`.`id` as `pivot_id`, `item_id`.`item_id` as `pivot_item_id` from `items` inner join `item_id` on `items`.`id` = `item_id`.`item_id` where `item_id`.`id` in (15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25))

Obviously my relations are wrong. Can anyone help me a little bit here?

Comment: Your `belongsToMany` relationship in the `Review` Model should be a `belongsTo` relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup of your relationship is slightly wrong.

You currently have a `hasMany` relationship with the inverse being `belongsToMany`, this is a many-to-many relationship.

This means that every Item has multiple reviews (which is right).
But this also means that every review applies to multiple items (which I believe is wrong).

To fix this you could replace the your `item()` function inside `Review` with the following:

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id','id');
}
```

This will change your relationship to be a one-to-many relation.

Every item still has multiple reviews but now every review is only linked to one item. This will also allow your other code (the controller) to work.

Furthermore you should remove the perentesis from your call in the view. Calling it as a function will return the relationship instead of the actual model.

Comment: Now it's working perfectly. Thanks for the well explanation! Will accept answer in 5min.